# Quick resource to learn more about all the JS height's

Tags: javascript, html, css

There're quite a few 'Height' associated properties in JavaScript (clientHeight, Window.height, scrollHeight, offsetHeight, etc.).

I can guess what they do, but I'd like a formal, detailed guide... Generic googling hasn't helped, any good sources I could use?

Answers with the details in 'em earn brownie points!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two resources worth consulting:

- [CSSOM View Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/)
- [W3C DOM Compatibility - CSS Object Model View](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html)

Below is a list of excerpt from the two (only one dimension has been included for each pair):

**`window.innerWidth` & `window.innerHeight`**
The dimensions of the viewport (interior of the browser window). The `innerWidth` attribute, on getting, **must** return the viewport width including the size of a rendered scroll bar (if any).

**`window.outerWidth` & `window.outerHeight`**
The dimensions of the entire browser window (including taskbars and such). The `outerWidth` attribute, on getting, **must** return the width of the client window. If there is no client window this attribute **must** return zero.

**`window.pageXOffset` & `window.pageYOffset`**
The amount of pixels the entire pages has been scrolled. The `pageXOffset` attribute, on getting, **must** return the x-coordinate, relative to the initial containing block origin, of the left of the viewport.

**`window.screenX` & `window.screenY`**
The position of the browser window on the screen. The `screenX` attribute, on getting, **must** return the x-coordinate, relative to the origin of the screen of the output device, of the top of the client window as number of pixels, or zero if there is no such thing.

**`screen.availHeight` & `screen.availWidth`**
The available width and height on the screen (excluding OS taskbars and such). The `availWidth` attribute, on getting, **must** return the available width of the rendering surface of the output device.

**`screen.height` & `screen.width`**
The width and height of the screen. The `width` attribute, on getting, **must** return the width of the output device.

**`<element>.clientLeft` & `<element>.clientTop`**
The position of the upper left corner of the content field relative to the upper left corner of the entire element (including borders). On getting, the `clientTop` attribute returns the computed value of the `border-top-width` property plus the width of any scrollbar rendered between the top padding edge and the top border edge.

**`<element>.clientWidth` & `<element>.clientHeight`**
The width and height of the content field, excluding border and scrollbar, but including padding. On getting, the `clientWidth` attribute returns the viewport width excluding the size of a rendered scroll bar (if any) if the element is the root element and the width of the padding edge (excluding the width of any rendered scrollbar between the padding edge and the border edge) otherwise.

**`<element>.offsetLeft` & `<element>.offsetTop`**
The left and top position of the element relative to its offsetParent. The `offsetTop` attribute, when called on element *A*, **must** return the value that is the result of the following algorithm: (1) If *A* is the HTML `body` element or does not have an associated CSS layout box return zero and stop this algorithm. (2) If the `offsetParent` of *A* is `null` or the HTML `body` element return the y-coordinate of the top border edge of *A* and stop this algorithm. (3) Return the result of subtracting the y-coordinate of the top padding edge of the `offsetParent` of *A* from the y-coordinate of the top border edge of *A*, relative to the initial containing block origin. (*) In case of an inline element that consists of multiple line boxes only the first in content order is to be considered for the purposes of the above algorithm.

**`<element>.offsetWidth` & `<element>.offsetHeight`**
The width and height of the entire element, including borders. The `offsetWidth` attribute, when called on element *A*, **must** return value that is the result of the following algorithm: (1) If A does not have an associated CSS layout box return zero and stop this algorithm. (2) Return the border edge width of *A*.

**`<element>.scrollLeft` & `<element>.scrollTop`**
The amount of pixels the element has scrolled. Read/write. The `scrollTop` attribute, when called on element *A*, **must** return the value that is the result of running the following algorithm: (1) If *A* does not have an associated CSS layout box return zero and stop this algorithm. (2) Return the y-coordinate of the content at the alignment point with the top of the content edge of *A*.

**`<element>.scrollWidth` & `<element>.scrollHeight`**
The width and height of the entire content field, including those parts that are currently hidden. If there's no hidden content it should be equal to clientX/Y. The `scrollWidth` attribute, when called on element *A*, **must** return value that is the result of the following algorithm: (1) If *A* does not have an associated CSS layout box return zero and stop this algorithm. (2) Return the computed value of the `padding-left` property of *A*, plus the computed value of the `padding-right` property of *A*, plus the content width of *A*.

Comment: @Abhishek I suppose you should be able to see a `start a bounty` link somewhere. However, ["A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067) Also, the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty).