# What is the Javascript equivalent for jQuery's width() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, width

I want to be able to calculate the width, in pixels, of an element that has the width css property set to `'auto'`.

I have tried `element.style.width` but didn't work because it returned `'auto'`. I notices that the jQuery function `width()` returns the length in px, but I cannot use jQuery to solve this, because it is not available in my page. So, does anybody know an equivalent method for jQuery `width()`?

Thanks.

Comment: Possibly related: [Quick resource to learn more about all the JS height's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826758/quick-resource-to-learn-more-about-all-the-js-heights/6826798#6826798).

Comment: The `getWH()` function in the [jQuery source](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js) will reveal the implementation. (Called with `name = "width"`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It basically comes down to `.offsetWidth`, but the jQuery code is a little more complicated due to cross-browser differences.

Comment: It's also wildly differently implemented in various browsers so using something as well-tested as jQuery for this makes sense..

Answer (score 17):

jQuery uses...

```
element.getBoundingClientRect().width
```

internally, it has some other stuff on top to deal with browser differences.

It returns an elements rendered size, where as .offsetxx returns sizes according to the box model.

```
element.getBoundingClientRect()
```

Is the most accurate way to get an elements "real" dimensions.

Here is a post by John Resig ( author of jQuery ) on the matter.

- http://ejohn.org/blog/getboundingclientrect-is-awesome/

Comment: Actually, very often `$el.width()` and `$el.outerWidth()` gives me zero, while `el.getBoundingClientRect().width` gives me the correct value, on both latest Firefox and Chrome, using jQuery 2.1.4

Answer (score 2):

Wasted 2 hours on this.
For my case other answers did not work so combining others answers & my findings  into one post with examples, for easy reading:

For an element like `select`, the `width()` in JQuery is same as `clientWidth` in JavaScript.

Sample code below, including output:

```
// Add jQuery library in HTML:
//   <head>
//       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
//   </head>

let eleId = 'myselectid1';    // NOTE: Provide your element id below

// jQuery
console.log( $('#' + eleId).width() );

// JavaScript
let ele = document.getElementById(eleId);
console.log(ele.clientWidth);                      // 58                // includes padding into calculation
console.log(ele.offsetWidth);                      // 60                // includes border size and padding into width calculation
console.log(ele.getBoundingClientRect().width);    // 60                // includes border size and padding into width calculation
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(ele, null).getPropertyValue("width"));    // 60px     (note the px in value, you may also get values like 'auto')     // all dynamic values for all CSS properties, IE>=9
console.log(ele.style.height);                     // empty string     // if you set it earlier, you would get this
console.log(ele.innerWidth);                       // undefined        // only works on window object, not on element like select/ div - fails in older IE<9
```

Hope that helps.