# How do I find the value of a JS style property if that property hasn't been specified anywhere in JS or CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, properties, center

How do I find the value of a **JS** style property if that property hasn't been specified anywhere in **JS** or **CSS**? **JS** only. No **JQuery** or other libraries please.

When I say the property hasn't been specified, I mean that nowhere in my code have I explicitly given it a value. For example, let's say I have a **div** tag with some text in it:

```
<div id="item" style="float:left;">This is just random text.</div>
```

The *width* of that **div** will of course be greater than 0 pixels due to the text inside, but it will be less than the *width* of an entire line because it is being floated to the left. The **div** will be just wide enough to fit all of that text inside, but I can't figure out what that *width* is because I never specified it. For example, trying this code:

```
alert(document.getElementById("item").style.width);
```

...will return an empty string because the *width* was never specified. Is there a way though, after the page has loaded and element has been rendered, to retrieve the computed/demonstrated/actual *width* of that **div** with **JS**?

I might as well let you know, by the way, that I am trying to put several of those containers, with the random text in the example above, spaced out and centered on the same line. I figured they have to be **divs** because the I need to manipulate the *margin* property to space them out (which can't be done with **spans**). And in order to force **divs** onto the same line, they have to be floated. But then the problem becomes that floated elements don't respond to the **center** tag or the **CSS** *text-align* property. So the only remaining way to center the containers is to give their container (the super-container) a *width* and set its **CSS** *margin* property to *auto*. But I don't know what to set the *width* of the super-container to, because the text within the inner containers will vary. So I figured the best course of action would be to figure out what the computed *width* of each inner container is and add up all the *widths* to get the *width* of the super-container. But if you see a flaw in that line of thinking, or an easier way to do it, feel free to point it out.

All advice is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: this might helpp you http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/147015-is-a-div-by-default-the-same-width-as-whatever-object-it-is-in/

width refers to the width of the content, excluding borders, padding and margins. auto automatically computes the width such that the total width of the div fits the parent

Comment: possible duplicate of [Quick resource to learn more about all the JS height's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6826758/quick-resource-to-learn-more-about-all-the-js-heights)

Comment: Is it a question or a tutorial....??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that is needed to get the width of the div is `divID.clientWidth` as shown below:

```
alert("Div Width: " + divID.clientWidth);
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5ERVj/18/).

Hope this helps :)